# Generate Unique Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, numbers, unique

I have an SQL Query

```
select substring(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            convert(varchar,sysdatetime(),121),
                        '-',''),
                    ' ',''),
                ':',''),
            '.','')
        ,1,18) as DATETIME
```

It is generating 18 digits Current Number like `201605011221374719`

How can I change this query to generate 11 digits Unique Numbers ?

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: You are aware that this is not necessarily unique, right? And what do you need - just a unique number, of any sort, or does it have to do something with the current date as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 18 to 11 in query:

```
select substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar,sysdatetime(),121),'-',''),' ',''),':',''),'.',''),1,11) as DATETIME
```

Comment: I want to run this query on 5 computers at a time. so i will not be unique at all. I need to put seconds and milliseconds in it. I mean it will be like this 05(Month)01(Day)12(Hour)40(Minutes)30(Seconds)2145(MilliSeconds)... Or we can check the current second of the day....i mean there are 86400 in 24 hours i can pick current second from this

Comment: please add this to question to make it more meaning full and why you need 11 digit unique number

Answer (score 0):

I hope a `right()` function around `sysdatetime()` can achieve what you need.

try below query

```
select substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar,right(sysdatetime(),18-5)
,121),'-',''),' ',''),':',''),'.',''),1,18) as DATETIME
```

Comment: @JaaZaib then u should include year,month,day,hour,min,sec..it is not possible with 11 digits..

Comment: Can Guid in c# help me to generate unique 11 digits code ?

Comment: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823) check this..substring of guid is not good

Answer (score 0):

NEWID() does not work for you? It's unique but has more digits than your required 11.

You can use NEWID() and then only take the first 11 digits (not sure whether this is enough unique for you).

```
select right(cast(rand(checksum(newid())) as decimal(15, 15)), 11)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I got solution now

Comment: substring of newid() of guid need not be unique all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with sql server 2012 or a later version, you can use the built-in [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function:

```
--                            123456789-12345678
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff') -- 18 digits
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dHHmmssffff') -- 11 digits
```

for earlier versions (2008 r2 and below), you can simply change the valuers of the substring - get the substring from the 8th char:

```
select substring(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            convert(varchar,sysdatetime(),121),
                        '-',''),
                    ' ',''),
                ':',''),
            '.','')
        ,8,11) as DATETIME
```

Note that by reducing the number of digits you are also reducing the uniqueness of the numbers - while thee 18 digits is unique for the next 10000 years, the 11 digit is only unique 10 days. changing to 12 digits will make it unique per month, and changing to 14 digits will make it unique per year.